# Transporting text from one worksheet to another with two Dynamic ranges- VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets (one for input and another for output) and I'm trying to copy some information on cells along a row from the input to cells along a row on the output. My code stops if, on a separated list of ranges, there's no info. The code I'm using is like that right now:

```
Sub Txt_Manobra()

Dim x As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim o As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim Txt1 As String
Dim Txt2 As Variant

For Each x In Worksheets("Formulario").Range("AK9:AK47").Cells
    If x.Value <> "" Then Txt1 = x.Value
        o = 8 + x.Count
        For i = 1 To 7
            p = 3 + i
            Txt2 = Worksheets("Formulario").Range(o, p).Value
            Worksheets("SdB pg1").Range(Txt1).Cells(1, i) = Txt2
        Next i
    Next x
End Sub
```

For each range value (x), it looks on the range txt1 (That is composed of only one row), and it should copy the values on range (D9:J9), one at a time and put on the range determined x (also only one row and with the same number of columns as D9:J9) then look on the next row (D10:J10) and so on.

I'm getting errors and I think this might be easier to do than I Think.

It's like that:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWW17.png)

And I want to tranfer to
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Hq2.png)

Each cell in the range "AK9:AK47" Contains a range like "P10:V10"

I haven't made it to work out to see if my "o" changes

Comment: add some images of a "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: What errors are you getting?  And on what line?

Comment: So in AK9:AK47 are cell addresses?? Like `A5`, `B10`, `E22`, etc?  And if that's the case, won't the variable `o` always result in 9 because `x` will always be 1 cell, so `x.Count` will always equal 1, +8 = 9...

Comment: Based on what @tigeravatar said, you probably need to change `Range(o, p)` to `Range(x.Row, p)`.   Hmmm, but if AK9 contains something like `A5:D5`, perhaps you are only wanting to copy `D9:G9` to `A5:D5` - I think we definitely need some sample data to look at.

Comment: Yeah. Practically I Want to copy D9:J9 to P10:V:10 in another worksheet. I'll try to simplify the code by using resize and excluding that For lines.

Answer (score 0):

If there are valid cell addresses in range AK9:AK47, then something like this should work for you.  Note that using single letter variables is bad practice, and you can customize the code by adjusting the constants at the top.

```
Sub tgr()

    Const sDestInfoCol As String = "AK"
    Const lHeaderRow As Long = 8
    Const lStartCopyCol As String = "D"
    Const lFinalCopyCol As String = "J"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDestInfo As Range
    Dim rDestTemp As Range
    Dim lNumCols As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Formulario")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("SdB pg1")
    Set rDestInfo = wsData.Range(sDestInfoCol & lHeaderRow + 1, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, sDestInfoCol).End(xlUp))
    If rDestInfo.Row <= lHeaderRow Then Exit Sub    'No data
    lNumCols = Columns(lFinalCopyCol).Column - Columns(lStartCopyCol).Column + 1

    For Each rDestTemp In rDestInfo.Cells
        With rDestTemp
            If Evaluate("ISREF(" & .Text & ")") Then
                wsDest.Range(.Text).Resize(1, lNumCols).Value = wsData.Cells(.Row, lStartCopyCol).Resize(1, lNumCols).Value
            End If
        End With
    Next rDestTemp

End Sub
```

Comment: Got incompatible types error on this line: "If Evaluate("ISREF(" & .Text & ")") Then". This is occurring very often with me as I'm dealing with range objects. Thanks for the advice on the variables I'm pretty new to VBA and in programming codes to.